# Assigning the return values of classmethod to the init variables

Tags: python-3.x

i am trying to assign the return values from the classmethod to the **init** method variables but shows the error "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object"

i tried assigning to one variable and could see that it returns "tuple"

```py
class port_mappings:

    ip_prefix=[]

    def __init__(self,node1_id,node2_id):
        self.node1_id=node1_id
        self.node2_id=node2_id
        self.node1_ip,self.node2_ip= port_mappings.gen_ip_prefix()


    @classmethod
    def gen_ip_prefix(cls):
        if len(cls.ip_prefix)==0:
            cls.ip_prefix.append("10.0.0.0/31")
            print(cls.ip_prefix)
            return "10.0.0.0/31","10.0.0.1/31"
        else:
            pass

node_list=port_mappings("95","96")
```

Since it is returning the tuple, i am trying the following but

```
self.node1_ip,self.node2_ip= port_mappings.gen_ip_prefix()
```

it shows the following error

> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Comment: What if `len(cls.ip_prefix) != 0`, then your function goes into the `else: pass` and returns `None`.

Comment: Hi primusa, i have some  other code to put in else block. First i need this assignment for this instance variable from the return method

Comment: Thank Primusa, for the second time initialisation it was hitting the else block. i fixed it now with some code in else block..thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this returns None is because you're calling gen_ip_prefix twice.

Once in class initialization `self.node1_ip,self.node2_ip= port_mappings.gen_ip_prefix()`

And then another time in your second block of code.

The first time you call the function it sees cls.ip_prefix as []. The entry of 10.0.0.0/31 is then placed into it, resulting in ["10.0.0.0/31"].

This means the second time you call the function, it sees the length as greater than zero and goes to your else statement. Since the else statement is the end of the function (so you actually don't need that else), and no return value has been defined at that point, None is returned.

None isn't an iterable, (not a tuple, list, etc), and therefore does not contain multiple values which could be unpacked in `a, b = function()` type statement.

Comment: Actually you are right, it made to think that i was testing the code without else block which got me stuck in this problem. i just added some code in else and it is returning and assigning those values. thank you delyeet

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are calling the `gen_ip_prefix()` method without any arguments, so your if condition: `f len(cls.ip_prefix)==0:` finds that the `cls` argument is `None` and then ends up in the else condition, where the function simply `pass`es and does not return a value. This is why you get the TypeError.

Comment: No Rob, if you run this with one initialisation it will work fine

Comment: if you add another instance for the same class it throws the error
node_list=port_mappings("95","96")

print(node_list.__dict__)

k=port_mappings("3","4")
print(k.__dict__)

Comment: Actually you are right, it made to think that i was testing the code without else block which got me stuck in this problem. i just added some code in else and it is returning  and assigning those values. thank you Rob